# SQL Server - Search for a column across all database tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to execute a SQL query to find all tables within a database that does not have a particular column?

E.g. I would like a list of tables that do not have a column called 'BranchID'.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Hint:  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Comment: I realize that we are dealing with tables and columns here but every single person with an answer has used INFORMATION_SCHEMA views. I have to agree with Aaron Bertrand that the catalog views are a better option most of the time. https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information Schema Views contain metadata about the database.  For more information, go [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx)

Using these views you can do something like this...

```
SELECT 
    t.TABLE_NAME
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME AND c.COLUMN_NAME = 'BranchID')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select table_name 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
except 
select table_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where column_name = 'BranchID'
```

(from memory, I might have the column names wrong but should get you most of the way there :) )

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
    SELECT table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT table_name
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns cc
        WHERE cc.table_name = c.table_name
            AND cc.column_name = 'Branch_id'
        )
```

First of all, we select the table_name from Information_Schema.Columns where the table_name is NOT in a query that selects tables WITH the Branch_ID Column

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES table to get the information you want using normal SQL Queries.

In your case you would use a subquery:

```
select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME NOT IN (select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME='BranchID')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a re-usable procedure that could help you.

```
CREATE PROC SP_UTIL_findcolumns
  @SearchString As varchar(250) = NULL
AS 
BEGIN
SELECT 
    t.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT TABLE_NAME 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c 
     WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME 
       AND c.COLUMN_NAME = @SearchString )
END
```